# How to use jwt for auth in server components NEXTjs

Tags: typescript, authentication, next.js, jwt, next.js13

when I store jwt in cookies or local storage I cannot use it in server components.

Before I was working with clerk lib for authentication. and there was function for server components to get user data. Maybe I can implement something like this with jwt

Comment: Struggling with the same.